# ektorp couchdb IllegalStateException content consumed

Tags: java, couchdb, illegalstateexception, ektorp

Its been a while since i've worked with Java especially exceptions. I'm in the process of adding ektorp couchdb intergration into something i'm working on. However i'm encountering content consumed exceptions.

The program in question uses twitter4j and i'm getting my statuses and writing them to a couchdb instance.

```
public void putTweet(Status status)
{
    Map<String, Object> newTweetDoc = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    String docname = status.getUser().getName() + " "
            + status.getCreatedAt().toString();
    newTweetDoc.put("_id", docname);
    newTweetDoc.put("User", status.getUser().getName());
    newTweetDoc.put("Contents", status.getText());
    newTweetDoc.put("Created", status.getCreatedAt().toString());
    newTweetDoc.put("RetweetCount", status.getRetweetCount());
    UserMentionEntity[] mentions = status.getUserMentionEntities();
    Map<String, HashMap<String, String>> formattedMentions = formatMentions(mentions);
    newTweetDoc.put("Mentions", formattedMentions);
    db.addToBulkBuffer(newTweetDoc);
}
```

At first i tried db.create(newTweetDoc) as well. Does the couchdbConnector need to be recreated every time i try this?

db is a global CouchDbConnector:
    public CouchDbConnector db = null;

```
public CouchTwitter()
{
    //create the db connection etc
}
```

It's the db.create(doc) or flushBulkBuffer that results in the error. Here is the stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Content has been consumed
at org.apache.http.entity.BasicHttpEntity.getContent(BasicHttpEntity.java:84)
at org.apache.http.conn.BasicManagedEntity.getContent(BasicManagedEntity.java:88)
at org.ektorp.http.StdHttpResponse.releaseConnection(StdHttpResponse.java:82)
at org.ektorp.http.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:111)
at org.ektorp.http.RestTemplate.post(RestTemplate.java:66)
at org.ektorp.impl.StdCouchDbConnector.executeBulk(StdCouchDbConnector.java:638)
at org.ektorp.impl.StdCouchDbConnector.executeBulk(StdCouchDbConnector.java:596)
at org.ektorp.impl.StdCouchDbConnector.flushBulkBuffer(StdCouchDbConnector.java:617)
```

I see in the above that two seperate Entity classes both call .getContent(), i've been playing around with my referenced libraries recently is it possible that its calling an old apache Http lib as well as the current?

Answer (score 0):

CouchDbConnector is thread safe so you don't need recreate it for each operation.

I have never encountered your problem, your use case is pretty simple and there should not be any problem saving a basic doc.

Verify that httpclient-4.1.1 or above is in the classpath.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I'll double check when i get home from work but i'm pretty sure its httpclient-4.1.4 plus core and the other commons packages.